# Hibernate Validation works only when saving and not on updating

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsp

I'm dwelling with this problem with form validating with Spring and Hibernate Validation.

I have a basic form with annotation validation.
When I add a new object, my validation works good, but when i try to update an existing object, the model annotations for validation works because che object is not updated, but I get no errors on the page, even if hasErrors is true..

I can't really understand what is happening... both methods (save and update) are similar

My Controller methods are:

```
// save New
    @RequestMapping(value = { path+"/new" } , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveLight(@Valid Luce luce, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return path+"/luce";
        }
        // Add message to flash scope
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "Luce aggiunta correttamente");
        luceService.saveLuci(luce);
        return "redirect:/"+path+"/"+luce.getIdLuce();
        }

    // Save updated
        @RequestMapping(value =  path+"/{idLuce}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String updateLuci(@Valid @ModelAttribute("luce") Luce luce, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, @PathVariable int idLuce, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

            if (result.hasErrors()) {

                logger.debug("Has errors is "+result.hasErrors());
                return "redirect:/"+path + "/"+luce.getIdLuce();
            }
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "Luce modificata correttamente");

            luceService.updateLuci(luce);
            logger.debug("ho aggiornato");
            return "redirect:/"+path+"/"+luce.getIdLuce();

        }
```

the JSP page is the same for the two operations and has, for instance,

```
<spring:bind path="numeroLuce">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">

                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="numeroLuce">Numero
                        Lampada</label>
                    <div>DEBUG: Status error is ${status.error}</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 form-field">
                        <form:input path="numeroLuce" id="numeroLuce" type="text"
                            class="form-control input-md" required="" />
                            <form:errors path="numeroLuce" cssClass="has-error" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
```

The logger on the controller says me that hasErrors is true, but when rendering the page I get DEBUG: Status error is false. This happens ONLY when i call the updateLuci method, not for the saveMethod, they have the same JSP template page.

Why they behave so different?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, I wrote it here in case someone has my same problem...

The problem was in the return statement of the `updateLuci` method.

It has not to be a redirect, but I have to show the same form view.

so it should be

```
 if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return path+"/luce";
    }
```

Hope this will help someone else